# Django REST - Can't access my edit page for my API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I have a code that lists all my posts in the API and it is doing what it is supposed to be doing. However, the code to edit the details of every posts wasn't working. What I am trying to do is that if I access the url for the post that I want to edit, I should be able to. But for some reason I can't. I thought I was doing the right thing.

I was trying to access the posts by their ids through the urls. But it only lists all my posts instead of the one with the matching `post_id` or primary key.

My codes are down below.

views.py

```
# To retrieve and list all posts
class ListPosts(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Posts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostsSerializer

# To view the details of the listed posts
class DetailPosts(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Posts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostsSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.ListPosts.as_view(), name="list_posts"),
    url(r'^(?P<post_id>\d+)/$',views.DetailPosts.as_view(), name="detail_posts"),
]
```

Comment: *"the code to edit the details of every posts wasn't working"*.. What is the behaviour?

Comment: add `lookup_fields = ('post_id')` in your `DetailsPosts` after serializer_class and be sure that add `post_id` in serialzer clas. You may be need to change `post_id` to `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `DetailPosts` view works, you must specify a `lookup_field` with the same name of your named parameter configured in `urls.py`. Be sure that this field is a `Posts` field which defines it uniquely

```
class DetailPosts(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'post_id'
    queryset = Posts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostsSerializer
```

### Use Viewsets and Routers

I also detect that your views an urls can be encapsulated by django rest framewok tools like [viewsets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) and [routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) since your views define a basic CRUD of `Posts`

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class PostsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Posts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostsSerializer
```

routers.py

```
from rest_framework import routers

from .views import PostsViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'posts', PostsViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```